# Sudoku board position hint

Tags: sudoku

As the title says, I'd like a hint (and an explanation why it is so) for the puzzle position in the attached image. I think I'm missing something really obvious but I can't figure it out.

Again though, I'd like the reasoning too, I can just look up the solution if that's what I wanted to do.

[image: This is my board position.]

Comment: You have two {7,8} cells in the fourth column, so those contain 7 and 8 in some order, so you can remove 3 from the third cell in that column and 8 from the sixth.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! Completely missed the (7,8) pair twice in a column!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

> You can remove 2,8 from A6 and A3 as it can only occur in A5 and A2 in that order.
>  Also, you can remove 7,8 from C4 and F4 as it can only occur in E4 and H4 in that order.
>
>  For reference of cells.
>
>
>  [image]

Comment: Yeah, similar to @Gareth McCaughan's comment, I didn't consider same pairs over the entire rows/columns. Thanks!